# How to get one div inside another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put my second div box inside my first div box how would i implement that ..

```
 <style>
 div {

width: 400px;
height:50px;
padding: 25px;
margin: 25px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}

#knob {
width: 50px;
 height:50px;
 background-color: grey;


 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Grade me in chrome</h1>

 <form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="angle" value="Horizontal" checked>Horizontal
  <input type="radio" name="angle" value="Vertical">Vertical
```

my second div would need to take up 25% of my first div how shall i do that or do i need to implement it another way?

Comment: There is no div. Write some code?

Comment: better create an [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) too

Comment: @HenryVarro http://jsfiddle.net/bsjkL158/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you shouldn't be styling the div like this.

Add a class and style based on the class.

```
.outer-div{
    width: 400px;
    height:50px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.inner-div{
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}


<div class="outer-div">
<div class="inner-div"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/yaqovokuce/edit

I have updated your jsfiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/qe81taap/

Element selector should be only used if the style needs to be reflected across all the element, otherwise use class or id selector

Comment: Okay thank you i modified it a little to be what i needed another question now if possible?

Comment: question?? pleasee???????????????